# Starting out with Python and Scrapy Nothing returned on scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Sorry for the newbie question i'm just trying to get to grips and everything was going well until i got stuck on this as it's not giving me any errors just giving no result.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/computing/tablets-and-ereaders/tablets/149_3402_32003_xx_xx/xx-criteria.html',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.xpath('//*[@class="product"]'):
        yield {
            'title': quote.xpath('//*[@class="productTitle"]').extract_first(),
            'price': quote.xpath('//*[@class="price"]').extract_first(),
            'image': quote.xpath('//*[@class="product-images"]/img/@src').extract(),
        }
```

Been working from the https://doc.scrapy.org/ and just a little stuck with this one, any advice would be amazing and possibly if there is any error handling that could help along the way.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the log of the spider execution ? Hard to tell what went wrong

Comment: @ClementLombard It's blank just opens a new line, that's why i was finding it so hard to understand the issue! :(

Answer (score 3):

Your `parse` method should be indented as a member of the `QuotesSpider` class:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/computing/tablets-and-ereaders/tablets/149_3402_32003_xx_xx/xx-criteria.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('In parse!')
        for quote in response.xpath('//*[@class="product"]'):
            self.log('Yielding {}!'.format(quote))
            yield {
                'title': quote.xpath('//*[@class="productTitle"]').extract_first(),
                'price': quote.xpath('//*[@class="price"]').extract_first(),
                'image': quote.xpath('//*[@class="product-images"]/img/@src').extract(),
            }
```

Comment: It was working previously with the example given in the docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/ it only messed up when i changed the xpath almost like the did something wrong with the Xpath, very strange.

Comment: Pepper in some `print()` functions to show results or better yet use the `pdb` Python debugger

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven ill have a look into that. Sorry for the newbie questions just trying to get a hang of it all :)